# Entering Value into Search Bar and Downloading Output from Webpage

Tags: html, web-scraping

I'm trying to search a webpage (http://www.phillyhistory.org/historicstreets/).  I think the relevent source html is this:

```
<input name="txtStreetName" type="text" id="txtStreetName">
```

You can see the rest of the source html at the website.  I want to go into the that text box and enter an street name and download an output (ie enter 'Jefferson' in the search box of the page and see historic street names with Jefferson).  I have tried using requests.post, and tried typing ?get=Jefferson in the url to test if that works with no luck.  Anyone have any ideas how to get this page?  Thanks,

Cameron

code that I currently tried (some imports are unused as I plan to parse etc):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from string import ascii_lowercase
import codecs
import os.path
import time


arrayofstreets = []



arrayofstreets = ['Jefferson']

for each in arrayofstreets:
    url = 'http://www.phillyhistory.org/historicstreets/default.aspx'
    payload = {'txtStreetName': each}
    r = requests.post(url, data=payload).content
    outfile = "raw/" + each + ".html"
    with open(outfile, "w") as code:
        code.write(r)
    time.sleep(2)
```

This did not work and only gave me the default webpage downloaded (ie Jefferson not entered in the search bar and retrieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing your reference to 'requests.post' relates to the requests module for python.

As you have not specified what you want to scrape from the search results I will simply give you a snippet to get the html for a given search query:

```
import requests

query = 'Jefferson'

url = 'http://www.phillyhistory.org/historicstreets/default.aspx'
post_data = {'txtStreetName': query}

html_result =  requests.post(url, data=post_data).content

print html_result
```

If you need to further process the html file to extract some data, I suggest you use the [Beautiful Soup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup) module to do so.

UPDATED VERSION:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from string import ascii_lowercase
import codecs
import os.path
import time

def get_post_data(html_soup, query):
    view_state = html_soup.find('input', {'name': '__VIEWSTATE'})['value']
    event_validation = html_soup.find('input', {'name': '__EVENTVALIDATION'})['value']
    textbox1 = ''
    btn_search = 'Find'
    return {'__VIEWSTATE': view_state,
            '__EVENTVALIDATION': event_validation,
            'Textbox1': '',
            'txtStreetName': query,
            'btnSearch': btn_search
            }

arrayofstreets = ['Jefferson']


url = 'http://www.phillyhistory.org/historicstreets/default.aspx'
html = requests.get(url).content
for each in arrayofstreets:
        payload = get_post_data(BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml'), each)
        r = requests.post(url, data=payload).content
        outfile = "raw/" + each + ".html"
        with open(outfile, "w") as code:
            code.write(r)
            time.sleep(2)
```

The problem in my/your first version was that we weren't posting all the required parameters. To find out what you need to send, open the network monitor in your browser (Ctrl+Shitf+Q in Firefox) and make that search as you would normally. If you select the POST request in the network log, on the right you should see 'parameters tab' where the post parameters your browser sent.

[image]

Comment: Hi Dziugas,  This is exactly what I tried.  I didn't get the correct output.  I edited my response above in the question